# How to convert this COUNT to INT?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

```
string query = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [PIN]) AS [pinCount] FROM [Users]";
DataTable dt = Execute(query);

if (dt == null || dt.Rows.Count == 0 || dt.Rows[0][0] == DBNull.Value)
    return false;
else if ((int)dt.Rows[0]["pinCount"] > 0)
    return true;
return false;
```

i have this kind of query in my code, and when casting the count to int, it gives me an exception that when castin the value must be less then infinite...what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @GrantWinney OP said the exception is on the line where it's being cast to `int` so `else if ((int)dt.Rows[0]["pinCount"] > 0)`.

Comment: Try using the `long` data type instead of `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
if (dt != null)
{
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        object tVal = dt.Rows[0][0];
        if (!Convert.IsDBNull(tVal))
            return (Convert.ToInt32(tVal) > 0);
    }
}
return false;
```